# Calling var i from for loop in jquery get request

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having trouble access var i in my $.get's scope. This is my code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < printer_ids.length; i++) {
  $.get('/get_printer_status_message/'+printer_ids[i]+'/', function(data) {
    $('#printer_status_'+printer_ids[i]).html(data);

    console.log(data)
    console.log('id: #printer_status_'+printer_ids[i]);
    console.log('current:' + $('#printer_status_'+printer_ids[i]).html());
  });
}
```

i is defined in the $.get line but not in $.get's scope. How do I access var i in $.get's scope?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to capture your `i` variable in a local scope:

```
for (var i = 0; i < printer_ids.length; i++) {
  (function (i){
    $.get('/get_printer_status_message/'+printer_ids[i]+'/', function(data) {
      $('#printer_status_'+printer_ids[i]).html(data);

      console.log(data)
      console.log('id: #printer_status_'+printer_ids[i]);
      console.log('current:' + $('#printer_status_'+printer_ids[i]).html());
    });
  }(i));
}
```

Comment: @user8957, While this answer is correct, since you seem to only use `i` to access `printer_ids[i]` perhaps it would be better to pass `printer_ids[i]` instead of simply `i`.

Answer (score 1):

An even better refactor that avoids redefining the function on each lap:

```
var doIt = function (printer_id){
    $.get('/get_printer_status_message/'+printer_id]+'/', function(data) {
      $('#printer_status_'+printer_id).html(data);

      console.log(data)
      console.log('id: #printer_status_'+printer_id);
      console.log('current:' + $('#printer_status_'+printer_id).html());
    });
};

for (var i = 0; i < printer_ids.length; i++) {
    doIt(printer_ids[i]);
}
```

Comment: Let's take this off-line

Comment: +1 to avoid creating an additionnal anonymous function on every loop iteration just to create a new scope and for passing `printer_id` instead of doing multiple property lookups by doing `printer_ids[i]` over and over.